# I set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release, but I noticed that NDEBUG flag was not set. Does this mean it's a debug build?

Tags: cmake

I'm working on an embedded application with 3d graphics that requires high performance. While investigating performance issues, I noticed that NDEBUG flag is not set. I also have confirmed that CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release. Isn't NDEBUG flag supposed to be set for release builds? Does NDEBUG flag not being set imply that this is a debug build?

I set it to Release build, but I also set it to -O2 optimization. Does this override the Release build and make it into debug?

Comment: "Isn't NDEBUG flag supposed to be set for release builds? - Yes, CMake normally sets this flag. If it is not your case, then probably `CMakeLists.txt` modifies that CMake settings. We need more details about your project, including the code. "I'm working on an embedded application" - Does this mean that you are **cross-compiling**? In that case toolchain could be responsible for set/not set NDEBUG flag. "Does NDEBUG flag not being set imply that this is a debug build?" - No, the build is **named** as Release. But it is the project who decides what is behind that name.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following code with CLion on my PC. When CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release, the program runs and exits with 0. When CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug, the assertion failed. It seems CMake or CLion automatically set NDEBUG when CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is set to Release. You can also explicitly set NDEBUG to make sure functions like **assert** do not affect the performance of your embedded program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    assert(1 == 0);
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test_ndebug)

add_executable(test_ndebug main.cpp)
```